# Why the old packages are still available in the official software center?

Tags: package-management, software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't  Ubuntu using the latest versions of some applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20830/why-isnt-ubuntu-using-the-latest-versions-of-some-applications)

- Netbeans IDE is still 6.9 in ubuntu center, but the current version is 7.0.1
- Eclipse IDE is still 3.5 in ubuntu center, but the current version is 3.7

I think there are many old(un-updated) packages available in software center. just noticed only the two.

**My Question is:**

If they are not updated there PPA, Why Ubuntu keeps them in the official software center?

Answer (score 1):

You missed the way Ubuntu provides software: every six month there is a new release, and the software do not get updated along this time, apart from security updates and bug fixes. Only some major software, like firefox, could be updated to a new version during the six months period.