# Why is the latest version of Miro not in the repositories?

Tags: installation, 11.10, repository, miro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't  Ubuntu using the latest versions of some applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20830/why-isnt-ubuntu-using-the-latest-versions-of-some-applications)

What's the reason that the available version of "miro" is only [3.5.1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=oneiric&searchon=names&keywords=miro) in Ubuntu 11.10?

The latest version of miro is [4.0.3](http://www.getmiro.com/download/all/), and there is still a [ppa available](https://launchpad.net/~pcf/+archive/miro-releases) with the latest version.

But why isn't miro available in the official repository?

Answer (score 0):

That's just the way that the Ubuntu Packages work, for most applications they don't have the latest versions. Using PPA's are probably the best way to circumvent this...

Comment: yes, but there is already the new version in the testing branch of debian:
http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=miro&searchon=names&suite=testing&section=all
why not in the current branch of Ubuntu 11.10