# Why are the packages found with apt-get always horribly out of date?

Tags: apt, package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't  Ubuntu using the latest versions of some applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20830/why-isnt-ubuntu-using-the-latest-versions-of-some-applications)

Whenever I use the package manager, it can only ever find *really* old versions of stuff. Example:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

The best it can do is version 8.4 (3 years out of date). Trying to get a later version, I get:

```
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package postgresql-9.1
```

I experience the same issue whenever I use the package manager, so I usually just download and build things from source.

How can I make it find up-to-date software?

Comment: It's available in PPA: https://launchpad.net/~pitti/+archive/postgresql

Comment: @EliahKagan You are absolutely wrong. The latest version of PostgreSQL in Ubuntu Software Center is 9.1. That's for Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: you can get it from here https://launchpad.net/~pitti/+archive/postgresql/+build/3870617/+files/postgresql-9.1_9.1.6-1~precise2_amd64.deb

Comment: what ubuntu version are you using, can you post the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: @EliahKagan You are saying that it is normal to see PostgreSQL 8.4 in apt-get because of ubuntu plan of Stable LTS Releases. that's not the case of Andrew because the latest version in repositories is 9.1/9.2

Comment: @AbrahamVanHelpsing thanks, that worked. I still want to know why the standard packages (not just postgres) are all really old as I have this problem every time I want to install something.

Comment: @Andrew please tell us what ubuntu version are you using and post the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: **@kamil** I wasn't actually saying that. Andrew brought up postgresql as an *example* to ask why often programs' latest versions are not provided in official repositories. At least that part of the question is a duplicate of [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20830/why-isnt-ubuntu-using-the-latest-versions-of-some-applications). But **if I had said that, I would not be wrong**. [Not all Ubuntu releases have postgresql 9.1.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=postgresql&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) **Andrew:** Please do edit your question with the info kamil has requested.

Comment: Think about what happens when you have a bunch of interconnected packages.  If you say "postgre is available so we'll bump the version to be that PPA in ****verse" how many reverse dependencies would break?