# Is it possible to upgrade to LibreOffice 3.6.5?

Tags: upgrade, updates, libreoffice

LibreOffice 3.6.5 has been released. Can Ubuntu 12.10 update to this productivity suite version, either automatically or manually?

https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Releases/3.6.5/RC2

Answer (score 5):

LibreOffice 3.6.5 has not arrived in official Ubuntu repositories yet. However, you can try this PPA maintained by the LibreOffice team to install the latest releases.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-3-6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lo-menubar
```

For better integration with Gnome desktops, you need to install this package:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-gnome
```

For KDE:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-kde
```

On the question why the latest version released by LibreOffice isn't in the Ubuntu repositories, please refer to this more general question: [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: @EliahKagan I've fixed this - there is a separate PPA for the 3.6.x branch, that *does* have 3.6.5 available at the time of writing.

Answer (score 1):

The new version will probably *not* be provided in the default-enabled repositories, and may not be officially packaged at all for Ubuntu 12.10, for quite some time (or ever). See:

- [Why doesn't Ubuntu ship an application, or the latest versions of some applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20830/why-isnt-ubuntu-using-the-latest-versions-of-some-applications)
- [Ubuntu wiki - StableReleaseUpdates](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates)

Once Ubuntu 13.04 is released, it may be provided in the backports repository (or may not). See:

- [Ubuntu help wiki - UbuntuBackports](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports?action=fullsearch&value=linkto:%22UbuntuBackports%22&context=180)

*Alternatively*, LibreOffice 3.6.5 *may* be provided soon, if it primarily provides security updates. (If it's a feature update, then whatever security patches are present would instead be ported to the version currently in your Ubuntu release, see the SRU policy linked above.)

#### You have a couple options for installing the new version now.

1. You can install the upstream version, [obtainable here](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/).

   This will not be maintained by Ubuntu's package manager. You'll have to take care of updating it yourself.

   It will probably work out-of-the-box but if you have problems, you *might* have to [remove the version provided with Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180403/how-to-uninstall-libreoffice).
2. You can *wait* for this version to provided in [the LibreOffice PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Elibreoffice/+archive/ppa). Currently the PPA [provides LibreOffice 3.6.4](https://launchpad.net/%7Elibreoffice/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=quantal). (That's still higher than 3.6.2, though, which is the version provided by the official 12.10 repositories.)

   [That](https://askubuntu.com/a/249486/22949) answer explain how to install from the PPA (or follow the instructions on the PPA page).
3. Apparently, there is [a separate PPA specifically for the 3.6 series, that does have 3.6.5](https://launchpad.net/%7Elibreoffice/+archive/libreoffice-3-6). This may be your best option. [That answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/249485/22949) explains how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the libreoffice ppa in order to get the latest updates... open a console and type:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa -y && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libreoffice && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y

Be careful, cause I putted the "-y" option there so it do everything without NO asking. Remove them if you want to audit the process. Also is a "one liner", each line of command is separated by "&&".

Cheers! :)

Comment: The PPA does not always have the very latest stable versions. In particular, it does not yet have 3.6.5. (It may soon.)