# Why is the version number of a package in Ubuntu repositories so different from its original one?

Tags: package-management

In synaptic I saw okular 4:4.13.3-0ubuntu0.1, and on [okular website](https://okular.kde.org/), the latest stable one is  Okular 0.21.

Why is the version of the Ubuntu one  so different?

How can I find out the actual version of okular in the Ubuntu one?

my Ubuntu is 64-bit 14.04.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't Ubuntu ship an application, or the latest versions of some applications?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20830/why-doesnt-ubuntu-ship-an-application-or-the-latest-versions-of-some-applicati)

Comment: I am asking why Ubuntu named the version of the package so different from its original one? Don't know how to tell what version the Ubuntu one is.

Comment: I have withdrawn the close vote, but leaving my previous comment, as others may also misinterpret your question as I did.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that the *4.13.3* part of version number does refer to version of KDE applications and not the version of okular. In July 2014 [KDE updates applications to version 4.13.13](https://www.kde.org/announcements/announce-4.13.3.php)  and as you can see on the download page  okular package has version 4.13.3.

As from the okular website :

> The last stable release is Okular 0.21, shipped as part of the KDE Applications 14.12 release.

the okular 0.21 was shipped with KDE version that is not currently in repository for 14.04 Trusty.

You can find the version of okular offered in rep. by looking at [Okular website's news](https://okular.kde.org/news.php) and finding which okular version was shipped with KDE version you see in Ubuntu reps.

Comment: Thanks. What are the versions of Okular and of KDE in Ubuntu 14.04 repository?

Comment: @Tim Okular should be 0.19  as KDE version (of applications) is 4.13.3

Comment: thanks. what is the KDE version for the latest okular 0.21? The site says "KDE Applications 14.12 release" but does 14.12 make sense?

Comment: @Tim [it does](https://dot.kde.org/2014/12/17/kde-applications-1412-new-features-frameworks-ports): "This release marks the beginning of a new style of releases replacing the threesome of KDE Workspaces, Platform and Applications in the 4 series which ended with the latest KDE Applications update last month."

Comment: @muru: my question is: is 14.12 the version of KDE, of okular, or of something else?

Comment: @Tim It's the version of "KDE Applications", successor to the [KDE Software Compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE_Software_Compilation#Fifth_series)

Comment: @muru: Then are "4.13.3" and "14.12" both versions of "KDE Applications"? Why is there such dramatic change?

Comment: @Tim: I think the starting 4 was dropped, so it's not really that drastic change from 13.3 to 14.12.

Answer (score 2):

The answer here is just so simple that it will likely get caught in the low quality answer queue. Simply drop to a terminal and issue the command `okular --version` or `okular -v`.

Source: http://stuff.onse.fi/man?program=okular&section=1 and/or `man okular`

Comment: I prefer before installing it.