# Who decides on which versions apt-get installs?

Tags: 16.04, apt

I'm not clear on how packages are included into the repos that `apt-get` queries.

For example, `redshift` is at v1.11, but the one that is installed via `apt-get install redshift` is 1.10.

Why is it using a verion that is over a year old, and how can I help to include the latest version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software) and [Why doesn't Ubuntu ship an application, or the latest versions of some applications?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20830/why-doesnt-ubuntu-ship-an-application-or-the-latest-versions-of-some-applicati)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packages and software that are available in the software center / repositories are (as far as I know) the version that the distro maintainers have determined is stable and tested at the time of the point release. This does not always mean that it is the latest available version of the software. For example, I am pretty sure Eclipse IDE is often a little behind in the Ubuntu repos which is why I regularly get the latest from their official servers. With most of these programs' code (like Redshift) being fully available on sites like github, you could always build it from source and have the newest one available. You could also search Google and see if someone is maintaining an up-to-date ppa. In your case, you may be on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS which is about a year old at this point. According to this link, Ubuntu 16.10 is using redshift 1.11 -
 https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/yakkety/universe/base/redshift